# How to find the library path that clang uses

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, clang, homebrew

I am new to clang. I am on a MacOS cataloina. I am using this command to compile some cpp code:

```
$ clang++ -std=c++11 Heartbeat.cpp opencv.cpp RPPG.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` -o test
```

This command works and I can run `./test` and everything goes well.

As you can see, I am using the library `opencv`. I installed this via brew (`brew install opencv`). When I run `ls /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.0_4/include/opencv4//opencv2/` , I see the entire opencv package. However, if I uninstall this and recompile, my code still compiles. This indicates I have opencv installed somewhere else. I've installed opencv in a conda virtual environment, but I can't see how that would effect things.

#### How do I print out the path to the `opencv` that clang uses so I can find the files?

I need to know because I am trying to see if I have `opencv2/face.hpp` installed.

#### EDIT

This is output from the original clang++ compile command PLUS adding -M:

```
clang: warning: -lopencv_dnn.3.4.10: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: -lopencv_highgui.3.4.10: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: -lopencv_ml.3.4.10: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: -lopencv_objdetect.3.4.10: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: -lopencv_shape.3.4.10: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: -lopencv_stitching.3.4.10: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: -lopencv_superres.3.4.10: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: -lopencv_videostab.3.4.10: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: -lopencv_calib3d.3.4.10: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: -lopencv_videoio.3.4.10: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: -lopencv_imgcodecs.3.4.10: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: -lopencv_features2d.3.4.10: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: -lopencv_video.3.4.10: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: -lopencv_photo.3.4.10: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: -lopencv_imgproc.3.4.10: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: -lopencv_flann.3.4.10: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: -lopencv_core.3.4.10: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files
```

Comment: duplicate is for gcc but clang has the same options

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thanks but I am confused. I entered `$ clang++ -M opencv` and I got
`clang: warning: opencv: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]`.

Comment: I also tried `clang++ -M opencv.hpp` and got `opencv.hpp:15:10: fatal error: 'opencv2/core.hpp' file not found
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.`

Comment: Not sure what's going on here, was hoping for just a print out of the relative path to the library?

Comment: run your normal command and just add `-M`, your object file will contain the used headers or add `-MD` to put them in a separate file

Comment: So I entered `clang++ -std=c++11 -M  Heartbeat.cpp opencv.cpp RPPG.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` -o test1` and I got output that I added to the question body. How do I interpret this?

Comment: `-M` doesn't compile so you don't need to add the linker flags, `-MD` is probably easier to use

Comment: Got it, thank you, this is just what I was looking for!

Comment: @AlanBirtles if you have the time, you ought to formalize that as an answer. As you can see there are a few subtleties that can trip up the unwary.

Comment: @user4581301 It's all there in the existing answers, its not something I've used before I just repeated what was in the existing answers

Comment: @AlanBirtles Shoot. My page was stale. Didn't notice you'd already closed the sucker.